# Check if Marker Image is valid

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am dynamically loading images to use in google maps.

I do so with the following code

```
var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../myurl');
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latlng, map: map, icon: markerImage, title: values[2] });
```

The problem is if that url is not valid, no errors are thrown, there are no exceptions. Also I cant check against the value (null or anything).

If the url is invalid the image doesnt show up. If the is valid it does show up. 
I tried the get.Icon method on marker but that just shows

anchor: undefined,
origin: undefined,
scaledSize: undefined,
size: undefined,
url:"../myurl"

Comment: Have you tried the Image Object? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLImageElement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try loading an image using your url and listening for `onload` and  `onerror` before passing it to the `google.maps.MarkerImage` constructor:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    // sweet, let's do this!
}
img.onerror = function () {
    // oops, something went wrong!
}
img.src = 'yoururl/whatever.png';
```